# How to trigger HTML5 validation error on button click

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a form which done in 3 steps. In first 2 steps validation errors doesn't showing because they have no submit button. How I trigger errors here?

[image]

Comment: You are most likely looking for the `checkValidity` API. Or, you could make the Next button a submit button, then cancel the submit event.

Answer (score -1):

So here's piece of code that will do your job....

```
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ //do this only after the whole thing is loaded, use this for more complex error handles...
    $('#form_').submit(function(data){ //this is triggered once you try to submit your data
    var Nerror = 0; //we declare the number of errors
        if($('#name_input').val()==''){  //here is where you handle errors, checking whether or not you 
            $('#name_input').addClass('has-error'); 
            $('#name_input').val('');
            Nerror++; //increment +1 to Nerror
            alert('no name');
        } 
        if($('#lname_input').val()==''){
            $('#lname_input').addClass('has-error');
            $('#lname_input').val('');
            Nerror++;
            alert('no last name');
        }
            if(Nerror>0){ //if Nerror is bigger then zero, we use the .preventDefault method to make sure the form is not submited
                data.preventDefault();
            }
    });

});
 </script>
<body>

  <form id='form_' action='your_next_step.php' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='name' id='name_input' required>   <!-- if you wish to make the inputs required, just put "required" inside the tags... -->
        <input type='text' name='lastname' id='lname_input' required>
            <button type='submit'>Next</button>
    </form> 
</body>
```

I hope you can do it now, if you have more complex handlers like checking your database for equal entries then you need to create a php file that makes that for you, then return the result in JSON or something....
Good luck.